# Who do I call to approve minor interior structural changes to my house?

Tags: structural, design, precautions

I want to knock down an interior wall in my house and make a dropped ceiling flush with the remainder of the room. It should be a fairly straightforward home improvement project that I am quite sure I can handle, however I would like to be totally certain and get a structural engineer to sign off. I would of course pay for his or her time.

Is it common for people to do? Who do I actually call? I don't think I should call a contractor because I want to do the work myself, but I want to make sure that what I plan to do is above board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to hire a structural engineer for consultation on your project. Find someone who does residential jobs. I did something similar for a remodeling project. The cost probably varies but the guy I work with is $180/hour. If you have to file a building permit you will have to do some kind of structural drawing showing the alteration and have the engineer put his seal on it indicating that he approves the plan.

Comment: Or hire a competent contractor for $35/hour for a simple job. For what one pays for an engineer, they could hire out the whole job.

Comment: That would work too. I wasn't sure if Matt was looking to have some help in making sure the plan is structurally sound.

Answer (score 0):

One question was left unanswered here when "Community" bumped it back to the top because it hadn't been "accepted" yet:

Yes. It's common for people to do that sort of thing. It's not something everybody's grandmother does, but it's certainly what I'd call common; nearly everybody I personally know (as in face-to-face "know") does things similar to what you're proposing to do. Of those who don't, half WOULD if they could just get past the illusion of "magic".